# Replace array values in string and make new string as per the values

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have one array which is range and on string which is test. Now I want to replace my range array values with {q1} and replace {w1} with it's values.
I added Expected output for my scenario

```
let range = [25, 50, 100, 125];
let w1 = 2
let test = '{w1} + {q1}'
```

**Expected output**

```
let string1 = 2 + 25;
let string2 = 2 + 50;
let string3 = 2 + 100;
let string4 = 2 + 125;
```

Comment: why you don't handle it by a simple loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
const range = [25, 50, 100, 125];
const w1 = 2;
const result = range.map(x=> w1.toString() + " + " + x.toString());
```

```js
const range = [25, 50, 100, 125];
  const w1 = 2;
  const result = range.map((x) => w1.toString() + " + " + x.toString());
  console.log("res", result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple achieve this using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [array destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```js
let range = [25, 50, 100, 125];
let w1 = 2;

const [string1, string2, string3, string4] = range.map(r => `${w1} + ${r}`);

console.log(string1);
console.log(string2);
console.log(string3);
console.log(string4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace string parts using [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) like this:

```js
const range = [25, 50, 100, 125];
const w1 = 2;
range.map(value => '{w1} + {q1}'.replace('{w1}', w1).replace('{q1}', value));
// ['2 + 25', '2 + 50', '2 + 100', '2 + 125']
```

But it's a bad practise. Much better to use string interpolation via [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) like this:

```js
const range = [25, 50, 100, 125];
const w1 = 2;
range.map(value => `${w1} + ${value}`);
// ['2 + 25', '2 + 50', '2 + 100', '2 + 125']
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of achieving this is by looping through the `range` array and pushing the desired strings to a new array.

```js
var range = [25, 50, 100, 125], w1 = 2, strings = [];

for(index of range.keys()){ 
  strings.push(`${w1} + ${range[index]}`);
  console.log(`string${index+1}: ${strings[index]}`);
}
```